# why Wordpress failed to load the resource? It said that the server responded with a status of 404 (not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, xampp

I'm beginner for developing website by using Wordpress. I follow the steps by steps in this URL: www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress_create_theme.htm

I have downloaded some template from other website. After I integrate with Wordpress, I also modify the code and adding some php code into it.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap 3 responsive centered columns">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
    <script>
    var template_dir_js = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>";
    </script>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.slidertron.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/skel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/skel-layers.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/modernizr.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/foundation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">         
             <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>            
        <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/skel.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style-desktop.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style-mobile.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/fakeLoader.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/gravity-forms-bootstrap.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/default.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/component.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/foundation-flex.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/foundation.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/foundation.min.css" />
    </noscript>
</head>
<!-- Header Wrapper -->
        <div id="header-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="12u">

                        <!-- Header -->
                            <header id="header">

                                <!-- Logo -->
                                    <h1><a href="index.html" id="logo">Beyond</a></h1>

                                <!-- Nav -->
                                    <nav id="nav">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="" class="arrow">Dropdown</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Magna phasellus</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Etiam dolore nisl</a></li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span class="arrow">Phasellus consequat</span>
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Phasellus consequat</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Magna phasellus</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Etiam dolore nisl</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Veroeros feugiat</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Veroeros feugiat</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="left-sidebar.html">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="right-sidebar.html">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="no-sidebar.html">No Sidebar</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </nav>

                            </header>

                        <!-- Banner -->
                            <div id="banner">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h2>Sed <span>nullam</span></h2>
                                    <p>Felis temper matinos elemer feugiat</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

It shows me the error:

```
jquery.slidertron.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/wordpress/sample-page/css/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

that means the css and javascript will not be read. Is there any solution for this error? I have tried many times but also cannot solve it. Please teach me how to solve this error. I need some help. Thank you

[File directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0RbE.jpg)
[CSS File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Poc.jpg)

Comment: I assume you cannot browse to : http://localhost/wordpress/sample-page/css/style.css can you even browse to http://localhost/wordpress/ ?

Comment: yes cannot browse

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has an asset pipeline that's based on enqueueing assets. [See more on this here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

Rather than adding stylesheet calls to your header template you need to add them to the enqueue file instead. Same with additional javascripts. Doing it this way means WordPress is aware of, and can easily work with, your assets.

Also make sure you've set up a child theme based on the original theme rather than working on the original. Then when that original theme is updated your changes aren't erased. [More on child themes here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Style.css tells WordPress on load the name of your theme or child theme and is required, so don't ever move or remove style.css from the theme's root directory.